# A good word for a group of synonyms?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a specific word that denotes a group of synonyms? I thought semantic field worked, but then I read that this just pertains to discernible words in a text/discourse that can be semantically related?

Synonym field? Synonym group?

Pretty sure there is a specific word I am looking for here

Comment: Really, it depends on what kind of mathematics you're going to use to hold them together -- fields are one kind of thing, groups are a quite different one. And, of course, it also depends on the actual nature of `IsA` link in the semantics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the most common term for this is *synonym cluster*. Here are some examples from Google Books:

> - A **synonym cluster** is a group of words that have similar meanings. The following four **synonym clusters** contain 20 vocabulary words. [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=0E5Xjvg_eYoC&q=%22synonym+cluster%22)]
> - Synonym coding uses a synonym list instead of wordlist. [*sic*] So, in synonym code, *D*<sub>*s*</sub> represents the synonym dictionary. The i<sup>th</sup> **synonym cluster** is noted [*sic*] by *Syn*<sub>*i*</sub>. [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=-2S5BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA234&dq=%22synonym+cluster%22)]
> - A 2nd study of 479 common terms grouped into 133 **synonym clusters** revealed the same structure in 2 samples of self-ratings and in 2 samples of peer ratings. [[link](https://books.google.com/books?id=QWRGAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22synonym+clusters%22)]

I think the motivation behind *cluster* as opposed to something like *group* or *field* is that it captures the idea that the synonyms are not usually *exact* synonyms, and the cluster is therefore not precise: different words in the cluster may be more or less closely synonymous, and the cluster will generally have a fuzzy boundary.

Comment: *Synonym cluster* captures it well.

Answer (score 0):

[**thesaurus**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thesaurus) (noun) is a book in which words that have the same or similar meanings are grouped together. (such as the online [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/definition)).

Comment: If I'm understanding the question correctly, I think the answer would be more like thesaurus *entry* or thesaurus *heading*.

Comment: @1006a  Thank you.  I appreciate that.

Comment: Downvote isn't mine, btw